# Default color for 3D scene

Tags: opengl, javascript, webgl

I have webgl 3D scene with background image and few shapes with textures.
I want to add some lines and other shapes and apply on them default color which not affect the shapes with textures.
How can I do this?
this is what I have now:

```
gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); //alpha=0 for background img
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
```

Comment: Question is ambiguous. Do you want to color the shapes? Or change the depth buffer color?

Comment: @Krythic, color the shapes that not have textures

Comment: It depends on what framework you're using. For OpenTK, GL.Color3(Color.Red);

Comment: Im using webgl in FireFox @Krythic

Comment: Most frameworks of OpenGL are 1:1 in terms of the api. Your case should be gl.color3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);

Comment: I get -"gl.Color3f is not a function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use shaders to apply color to objects..

In fragment shader you can specify it with 
    gl_color = vec3(r,g,b,a);

Glcolor3f it's deprecated..